# Inserting multiple record on a form submit - Yii

Tags: php, yii

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new events;      


    if(isset($_POST['events']))
    {

        $model->event_title         =   $_POST['events']['event_title'];
        $model->event_description   =   $_POST['events']['event_description'];
        $model->event_repeat_option =   $_POST['events']['event_repeat_option'];
        $model->event_start_date    =   date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $model->event_end_date      =   date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $model->user_id             =   yii::app()->user->getState('user_id');
        $model->deal_id             =   "1";
        $model->event_type          =   "1";
        $model->event_creation_date =   date('Y-m-d H:i:s');    


        if($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->event_id));
    }
}
```

Inserting multiple records? Why? 
No Bug, No Error... Data is inserting Perfectly... but Multiple records at a time.

I did Print_r($model->attributes);

```
Array
(
    [event_status] => 1
    [event_title] => test1
    [event_description] => test1
    [event_repeat_option] => test1
    [event_start_date] => 2012-05-15 18:45:40
    [event_end_date] => 2012-05-15 18:45:40
    [user_id] => 3
    [deal_id] => 1
    [event_type] => 1
    [event_creation_date] => 2012-05-15 18:45:40
    [event_id] => 
)
```

... Everything is fine there but still some bug... can't track it. Any suggestion?

Model Attributes

```
/**
 * This is the model class for table "user_events".
 *
 * The followings are the available columns in table 'user_events':
 * @property integer $event_id
 * @property integer $user_id
 * @property string $event_type
 * @property integer $deal_id
 * @property string $event_creation_date
 * @property string $event_start_date
 * @property string $event_end_date
 * @property string $event_title
 * @property string $event_description
 * @property integer $event_repeat_option
 *  *
 * The followings are the available model relations:
 * @property Deals $deal
 * @property RepeatOptions $eventRepeatOption
 * @property Users $user */
```

Comment: what is the bug? what error? what did you expect and what happened? the question needs more explanation.

Comment: No Bug, No Error... Data is inserting Perfectly... but Multiple record at a time.

Comment: ok..the create code is fine..how many records are inserted? and what are the values?same?..good that you edited question

Comment: yes i have checked it, i think it is an issue with afterSave(), are you overriding afterSave() in the model?, if yes, then please show afterSave() code, if not, answer my previous comment's questions.

Comment: What do you mean with "but multiple record at a time"? You mean more than one record is saved in the database?

Comment: yup its inserting 2 records on submitting form once..

Comment: nop...but i was using beforeSave()... I did comment it.. but still same result

Comment: Are you using some jquery/javascript on the form you are submitting?

Comment: dlnGd0nG could be right check firebug, to see how many calls are going to controller url

Comment: @dInGd0nG... Perfect.... Some how i did update my code on  'enableAjaxValidation'=>TRUE...

now False it... working perfect... 
Thanks...

Comment: btw, you can do ajaxValidation and not have this problem, check some examples on how to use ajaxValidation, and you'll know, there will only be slight changes in your create method.

Comment: `<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
 'id'=>'events-form',
 'enableAjaxValidation'=>TRUE,
 'method'=>'POST',
));`

its sending data without clicking on submit button.. that's why it was updating multiple records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's because of AJAX validation witch is sending a request to the createAction (in your case). You can turn off ajax validation in your form widget like:

```
    $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
        'id'=>'your-form',
        'enableAjaxValidation'=>false, //<- this is important      
    ));
```

But if you really need ajax validation you can check for ajax requests in your controller like:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
$model=new events;      


if(isset($_POST['events']))
{
    ... //Your stuff. Assigning attributes etc.
    if(!Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest){
        if($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->event_id));
    }
}
```

}

In this case it will only save a record when its not an ajax request :). Try it out and i hope that's what you're looking for.

Regards